# How to give PHP permissions to write to files without globally opening up permissions to the directory

Tags: php, centos, permissions, configuration

I'm running Centos 5.5. I need to create / write some files with a PHP script. The script only works if I have the permissions of the directory in which the files are to be created / written set to writable for everyone, ie:

```
chmod a+w my_directory
```

The script is working fine, but having my directory writable like that is obviously BAD.

My question is, is there a way to allow selected programs (such as PHP) permission to write and create files while keeping everyone else out?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the files/directories PHP needs to write to owned/writable by the user or group that PHP is running as (usually your web server's user/group).

Note that while this configuration is *more secure* than world-writable files it is only as secure as your code and your webserver configuration.  Plan accordingly.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I know I can change the user permission with chown and the group permission wih chgrp (and chown), but could you tell me how I find out which group or groups php is running as please. I know you can use groups <username> but 'groups php' isn't working.

Comment: Put this in a page on your website and see what it returns.`<?php passthru(id);?>` This is for Linux.

Comment: @ablackhat - Thanks for that. I get that the group id and user id is apache. I also did a 'cat /etc/group' command which I've just read about and apache was in there. But how do I specifically get the user and or groups that php belongs to? Can php belong to anything? I'm assuming I have to change the file permissions inmy directory to apache. But I'm really not sure if I have to do that just for the user or root or both and importantly why? Cheers.

Comment: @Joe - PHP is executed as the user/group running the web server, absent other specific configuration changes.

Comment: I've changed both the user and the group for the relevant directory to 'apache' which has sorted out my problem. What is the difference between changing the group and the user?

Comment: @Joe - One is the user, and one is the group (not being facetious - that's really the difference).  See http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/users.html for what's probably a better explanation, specifically the introduction and the section on groups which talk about how permissions/access are determined :-)